# Como se puede usar google maps API para graficar una trayectoria dada en longitud y latitud?

Tags: google-maps

Tengo un conjunto de puntos (latitud, longitud) en un archivo de texto.

Usando solo uno de esos datos puedo ver en google maps donde esta.

Me gustaria consultar eso para 100 o mas datos asi que hacerlo a mano no es practico.

Se puede usar el API de google maps para automatizar esto y ver la trayectoria?

Ejemplos tutoriales o consejos son bienvenidos

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR: 3 cosas: 1. Investiga 2. Intenta. 3. Edita la pregunta y agrega todos los detalles que demuestren los 2 puntos anteriores, de esta manera incrementas la chance de obtener una buena respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: investiga un poco e intentalo, como sea te dejo algo que espero te sirva para empezar:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/how-to-draw-infinite-route-with-more-than-10-locations-on-go/

Comment: Precisamente eso es lo que es esta pregunta: Investigacion. Gracias por los punteros, empezare por alli.

Comment: Mi problema es que no se si es posible, o por donde empezar. Por lo cual leere los enlaces que me dejaron